# How can I add pillow and qrcode to yocto image?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, yocto, bitbake

I need to add to my yocto image pillow and qrcode (Python3) to my yocto image, Yet i kinda struggle. I know there's arleady a recipe but whenever i try to add i get the following error:

**Nothing RPROVIDES 'python3-qrcode'/'python3-pillow'**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`python3-pillow` exists in `meta-openembedded/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python`, but `python3-qrcode` I did not find it, it was before added to meta-security but I think they removed it.

Anyways, here is the recipe if you want to add it to your custom layer:

- **meta-custom/recipes-python/python/python3-qrcode_6.1.bb**:

```sh
SUMMARY = "QR Code image generator"
SECTION = "devel/python"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=4b802d2a65df4626623c79757f486af9"

PYPI_PACKAGE = "qrcode"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "505253854f607f2abf4d16092c61d4e9d511a3b4392e60bff957a68592b04369"

inherit pypi setuptools3
```